# How to remain logged in when switching languages via domain Drupal 7

Tags: users, i18n-l10n, domain-access, cookies

I've got a site which will run in different languages. 
The language is determined based on the language domain, and the site will thus exists as **example.com**, **example.de**, **example.fr**, **example.co.uk** and so on. All sites run on the same codebase and database.

I've experimented with `$cookie_domain` in `settings.php`, but cookies will not be shared across top level/language domains. I've also had a look at the `Bakery module`, but that does not work for top level/language domains either.

Does anyone have experience with this, or does anyone know what my options are?

Comment: You can't share cookies across different domains, period. And example.com is obviously a completely different domain to example.de, so you can't share cookies across those (this isn't a limitation imposed by Drupal, it's a restriction of HTTP). Anything you could try to do would be a hack/workaround, which you'll need to solve separately to Drupal first, and then try to integrate back in afterwards. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies for some ideas